# Formatar String depois que é convertida do HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Fiz um código que transforma todo o HTML em uma String, porém, ao fazer isso o código está vindo assim:

```
<div class=\"page\">\r\n<div class=\"bloco\">\r\n   <table id=\"canhoto\">\r\n
```

Os caracteres \r\n eu já consigo remover, só que agora preciso arrumar um jeito de remover aquelas barras que fica por exemplo na class da div, eu gostaria de deixar ela assim: class="page", mas elas estão todas assim: class=\"page\", eu gostaria de alguma forma tratá-las para que ela não fique assim, e fique da forma correta.

```
string HTMLemString = RenderizaHtmlComoString("~/Views/Item/Item.cshtml", id);
        var regex = new Regex("(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<style(.+?)\\</style\\>)|(<link[^>]*>)",
            RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        HTMLemString = regex.Replace(HTMLemString, "");
        HTMLemString = HTMLemString.Replace("\0", "");
```

A parte que trato o código é esta.

```
string CSSdocumento = CSSemString();
        Byte[] bytes;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    var HTMLconversão = @HTMLemString;
                    var CSSconversão = @CSSdocumento;


                    using (var msCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CSSconversão)))
                    {
                        using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTMLconversão)))
                        {
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, msCss);
                        }
                    }

                    doc.Close();
                }
            }

            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "teste.pdf");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
```

E acima o código onde eu gero o PDF.

Comment: mostra o codigo.. e qual o intuito final. porque pode ser que nao faca sentido criares uma funcao para converter html para string..

Comment: Ah sim, é para eu converter para PDF em seguida, estou usando o iTextSharp, só que quando ele cria o pdf, ele é gerado em branco, dai estou achando que é algo relacionado ao html, em como ele esta vindo na string. Estou usando este exemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp

Comment: nao me parece q seja por isso.. mas nao tenho a certeza, estas a usar o itextsharp por algum motivo?

Comment: Sim, no caso ali, eu gero uma string do html, e uso o itextsharp para criar através da string o pdf, igual o link do exemplo que eu postei.

Comment: Talvez você precise do [`Regex.Unescape`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822843/itextsharp-html-to-pdf

pelo que vi parece haver algum bug com isso.. ai nessa resposta tem uma solucao:

```
 Document document = new Document();
    try
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("c:\\my.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string htmlText = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:59500/my.html");
        Response.Write(htmlText);
        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(htmlText), null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }

        document.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
```

Comment: Então mas neste como eu colocaria o CSS? pois no outro eu passo o CSS inteiro dentro de uma string.

Comment: poes o css integrado dentro do html por ex. porque tens o css à parte?